# how to combine a return value with text

Tags: javascript

I want to combine the return value of the ukaccess function into the value set by the setarea function but I'm not experienced enough to know what to do next. Hopefully, the code is correct so far.

```
function ukaccess(){

    var dbasedata = document.forms[0]._dbase_name.value;
        dbasedata = dbasedata.toUpperCase();

    if  (dbasedata.indexOf("UK_CONTACTS")>-1) {
        return "UK_CONTACTS";
    }
    }


function setarea(){

    var postcode2 = document.forms[0]._postalcode.value;
    var trim_pcode = (postcode2.substr(0,8));
        trim_pcode = trim_pcode.toUpperCase();
        trim_pcode = trim_pcode.replace(/\s/g, "");

    if (trim_pcode == "W1W6UW" || trim_pcode == "W1G8HU") {
        //alert("London-Xover");
        document.forms[0]._area.value = "North London" [ukaccess function return value here];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
document.forms[0]._area.value = "North London" + ukaccess();
```

Comment: many thanks, I already tried that. must be something else wrong in the code i guess.

Comment: did u try returning the value to a different variable and then adding that? var TEMP = ukaccess(); and then  document.forms[0]._area.value = "North London" + TEMP; or try using the concat method in JS http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_string.asp

Comment: Thanks for that. It did work in the end, I had something else wrong in another part of the page :-s Oh the joys of a steep learning curve.

Comment: @user1424626: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Accept an answer as correct if it suites you right.